How to connect to a R2DBC postgres schema
I have been having trouble connecting to R2DBC postgres schema. Just like we have a jdbc connection string which we use in Dbeaver or PgAdmin to visually see the tables and run query what is the equivalent for reactive postgres DB. I read everywhere that pgAdmin and Dbeaver dont support R2DBC connections and when I try the same in these i get errors like :

My application.yml looks like this I am working on reactive spring boot so a reactive DB:
reactivepostgresqlurl: 'r2dbc:postgresql://postgres:5432/samplePostgresDB'
reactivepostgresqlusername: admin
reactivepostgresqlpassword: admin

I tried using Docker as well :

when i hit my api endpoint i get this :
Caused by: io.r2dbc.postgresql.PostgresqlConnectionFactory$PostgresConnectionException: Cannot connect to postgres/<unresolved>:5432

Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: postgres


It is just a database, replace r2dbc with jdbc to connect to the same database.

@M.Deinum in PgAdmin Im getting this error after i replace r2dbc with jdbc - Unable to connect to server: (Errno 8] nodename nor servname provided, or not known . Getting this in Dbeaver - The connection attempt failed.

@M.Deinum Would not be here if I knew everything.
